# A3/A4/A6 alloys on an A5

Tags: tires, wheels, audi

I have an Audi A5 and I want to put genuine Audi 7-double-spoke alloys on it. The problem is as far as I know these alloys are only created in 20" for the A5.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use either 18" or 19" alloys from an A3/A4/A6 on and A5? And if so what is needed (e.g. spacers) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a listing of Audi wheel fitment I pulled from [this site](http://www.wheelfitment.net/audi):

```
Model       Year        PCD     Offset      Bore
100         90 to 94    5×112   35 to 45    57.1
200         90 to 94    5×112   40 to 45    57.1
80          92 to 95    4×108   35 to 45    57.1
90          92 to 95    4×108   35 to 45    57.1
A2          00 on       5×100   38 to 45    57.1
A3          96 to 03    5×100   35 to 45    57.1
A3          03 on       5×112   45 to 50    57.1
A4          95 on       5×112   35 to 45    57.1
A5          07 on       5×112   20 to 35    66.6
A6          95 on       5×112   35 to 45    57.1
A8          02 on       5×112   35 to 45    57.1
A8 S8       02 on       5×112   35 to 45    57.1
Allroad     00 to 06    5×112   15 to 25    57.1
Allroad     06 on       5×112   35 to 45    57.1
Cabriolet   92 on       4×108   35 to 38    57.1
Coupe       92 to 95    4×108   35 to 45    57.1
Q5          08 on       5×112   35 to 45    57.1
Q7          06 on       5×130   45 to 55    71.5
RS4         01 on       5×112   20 to 30    57.1
RS6         02 on       5×112   35          57.1
S3          98 to 03    5×100   35 to 45    57.1
S3          03 on       5×112   42 to 50    57.1
S4          99 on       5X112   35 to 45    57.1
S6          94 on       5×112   35 to 40    57.1
S8          01 on       5×112   20 to 30    57.1
TT          99 to 06    5×100   25 to 45    57.1
TT          06 on       5×112   42 to 50    57.1
```

I believe all sizes are in millimeters. Looking at the list, it looks as though the A5 is a strange bird. The bore size is much larger (almost 10mm). The offset is quite different as well, though the bolt pattern is the same.

**EDIT:** I just re-read what I had written and realized a spacer will not work. It would work the other way if you were putting an A5 wheel on one of the others, but not the other way around. The offset may not be an issue, but the bore size *will* be an issue. There is no way without machining to put the 57.1mm bore on the 66.6mm bore of the A5.